# Spring JWT Filter Configuration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, jwt

I want to add a Filter to authenticate users with token. I achieve this by adding two filters:

```
public class JwtFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

private TokenAuthenticationService authenticationService;

public JwtFilter(TokenAuthenticationService service) {
    this.authenticationService = service;
}

public JwtFilter() {
}

@Override
public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request,
                     final ServletResponse response,
                     final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    System.out.println("JwtFilter.doFilter");
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(
            authenticationService.getAuthentication((HttpServletRequest) request));
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

After that I created the second Filter, to authorise users:

```
public class StatelessLoginFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {


private final TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService;
private final UserDetailsService userService;

public StatelessLoginFilter(String urlMapping, TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService,
                            UserDetailsService userDetailsService, AuthenticationManager authManager) {
    super(new AntPathRequestMatcher(urlMapping));
    this.userService = userDetailsService;
    this.tokenAuthenticationService = tokenAuthenticationService;
    setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
}

@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
    System.out.println("StatelessLoginFilter.successfulAuthentication");
    // Lookup the complete User object from the database and create an Authentication for it
    final User authenticatedUser = (User) userService.loadUserByUsername(authResult.getName());
    final UserAuthentication userAuthentication = new UserAuthentication(authenticatedUser);

    // Add the custom token as HTTP header to the response
    tokenAuthenticationService.addAuthentication(response, userAuthentication);

    // Add the authentication to the Security context
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(userAuthentication);
}

@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException {
    System.out.println("StatelessLoginFilter.attemptAuthentication");
    final User user = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), User.class);
    final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken loginToken = new U

sernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());
        return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(loginToken);
   }
}
```

And here is my SecurityConfiguration:

```
    @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService;



    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()

                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/user/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll().and()
                .addFilterBefore(new StatelessLoginFilter("/login", tokenAuthenticationService, userDetailsService, authenticationManager()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(new JwtFilter(tokenAuthenticationService), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception{
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
     auth .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return userDetailsService;
    }

}
```

Now, when I send request to "/login" I get 404 error page. Trully, I don't have Controller mapped, but in security there is a url mapping in security config. As I've read in docs :

> Creates a matcher with the specific pattern which will match all HTTP methods in a case insensitive manner.

Also, you can see System.out.println() lines.I put breakpoint here, but execution doesn't reach this lines. I'm not sure if I registered this filters properly. My code mostly base on this repository:https://github.com/BranislavLazic/angular-security

Answer (score 2):

[Springboot JWT Starter](https://github.com/bfwg/springboot-jwt-starter) is a good way to start a stateless springboot application using JWT.

Write your SecurityConfiguration like below.

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy( SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS ).and()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint( restAuthenticationEntryPoint ).and()
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationTokenFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/index.html", "/login.html", "/home.html").permitAll()
              .anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and()
            .formLogin()
                .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler).and()
            .logout()
                .addLogoutHandler(jwtLogoutHandler())
                .logoutSuccessHandler((new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler(HttpStatus.OK))) ;
}
```

Filter

```
@Override
public void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    String authToken = getToken( request );
    // get username from token
    String username = tokenHelper.getUsernameFromToken( authToken );
    if ( username != null ) {
        // get user
        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername( username );
        // create authentication
        TokenBasedAuthentication authentication = new TokenBasedAuthentication( userDetails );

        authentication.setToken( authToken );
        authentication.setAuthenticated( true );
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    }

    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

For more info, check out the source code:
https://github.com/bfwg/springboot-jwt-starter/blob/master/src/main/java/com/bfwg/security/auth/TokenAuthenticationFilter.java